# RE: CherryPy and Selecting the Host and Port from the Command Line and/or with What File?

Tags: python-3.x, file, port, host, cherrypy

I do not know which file to view in /cherrypy to change the host and port to view my server online from my 32-bit ARM device.

...

Which file can I use to change the interior parts to that file so I can use 0.0.0.0:? And...is it possible to use cherrypy from the command line to switch things around for the host and port?

Seth

P.S. I found many items of interest on this site dedicated to the source cherrypy and the rearrangement of the port but not of the host. I do not want to use 127.0.0.1 any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed some answers online and actually found an answer.

```
cherrypy.engine.stop()
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 5000})
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

This amount of info. updates your host and port so you can route things a bit differently.

...

Comment: You shouldn't have to stop the engine.

Comment: Okay...I guess I could change the answer if possible. I will test it again.